# EE & CartThrob: Conditional Not Working?

Tags: ee2, cartthrob

I've been looking at this for a bit, so maybe my eyes are just fried right now, but I can't seem to figure out why the following conditional is not working:

```
{if {total_items} != "0"}  
                        <div class="paddingleft36">
                            {if {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal prefix=""} >= "40"}
                                <div>Delivery Options<br />
                                <input type="radio" name="delivery_option" value="pickup">Pickup<br>
                                <input type="radio" name="delivery_option" value="delivery">Deliver to:
                                </div>
                            {if:else}
                                {exp:channel:entries channel="cart"}
                                <div>{pickup_only_notice}</div>
                                <div class="cart_options topminus">{delivery_minimum_notice}
                                </div>
                                {/exp:channel:entries}
                            {/if}
                        </div>
                    {/if}
```

Right now, it just spits out the {if:else} portion of the code, even if the shopping cart subtotal is greater than or equal to ( >= ) 40. When the subtotal is over 40, the Delivery Options radio boxes should appear, but they don't.

This is very confusing and I assume that it might have something to do with the {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal prefix=""} tag, but this is precisely how the CartThrob documentation suggests creating conditionals with the cart subtotal (e.g. stripping the currency prefix ($) to compare values.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping that cart_subtotal tag in quotes inside your conditional.

I just tried this out and it worked for me:

```
{if '{exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal prefix=""}' >= '40'}
    Delivery Options Code
{if:else}
    This is the else statement
{/if}
```

This worked with subtotals containing decimal values and also worked if I specified a number with a decimal as the compare value.

Not sure if prefix="no" was just a mistype, but by adding prefix="no" you're going to end up with something like "no30" as the subtotal value you're trying to compare. I think that will always evaluate as greater than 40.

Answer (score 1):

I came to the solution for this about 10 minutes after I drafted this question, so I thought I'd share it with anyone who might be stuck on this one. It's simple, but might save some time and hair-pulling.

It turns out the "decimals" parameter in CartThrob's {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal} tag must be set to "0" to properly compare its value with another number (even if that other number also contains a decimal). This seems illogical, but it's the way works.

Works properly:

```
{if {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal prefix="no" decimals="0"}[/code] >= "40"}
{if:else}
{/if}
```

Does not work properly:

```
{if {exp:cartthrob:cart_subtotal prefix="no"}[/code] >= "40"}
{if:else}
{/if}
```

Maybe a newbie solution, but a solution nonetheless. :D